# UWP ListView Drop get index

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop

I have 2 ListViews, I can drag an item from ListView1 and drop it on to ListView2. If I drop the item between other items I want the item to be added in that same location.

So the question is: **How do I get the position/index where I dropped my item?**

I would expect to find the index somewhere in the DragEventArgs of the Drop event, but I can't find it anywhere:

```
private async void ListView2_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway: I have tinkered around with this code and finally got it to work to my needs:

```
    private async void MyListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListView, 0), 0) as ScrollViewer;
        var position = e.GetPosition((ListView)sender);
        var positionY = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + position.Y;
        var index = GetItemIndex(positionY, MyListView);

        // do something useful with the index... 
    }

    int GetItemIndex(double positionY, ListView targetListView)
    {
        var index = 0;
        double height = 0;

        foreach (var item in targetListView.Items)
        {
            height += GetRowHeight(item, targetListView);
            if (height > positionY) return index;
            index++;
        }

        return index;
    }

    double GetRowHeight(object listItem, ListView targetListView)
    { 
        var listItemContainer = targetListView.ContainerFromItem(listItem) as ListViewItem;
        var height = listItemContainer.ActualHeight;
        var marginTop = listItemContainer.Margin.Top;
        return marginTop + height;
    }
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the currently accepted answer has an occasional crash when `ContainerFromItem` returns null (I think it's either something to do with virtualization or the container just not being materialized yet)

In case it's useful for others, the solution I've come up with is a bit simpler and should work even for virtualized lists:

```cs
public static int GetDropIndex(this ListView listView, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(listView);

    foreach (var item in listView.Items)
    {
        var container = listView.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
        if (container != null)
        {
            var bounds = container.TransformToVisual(listView).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight));

            // Check to see if the bounds of the item's container intersects the drop point
            if (bounds.Top > position.Y)
            {
                // Get the list view to tell us the index of the hit container
                return listView.IndexFromContainer(container);
            }
        }
    }

    // The drop occurred after the last item in the list
    return listView.Items.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the position/index where I dropped my item?

Currently, `Drop` event does not provide the index of your dropped item. But you could get the drop position with [`GetPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.drageventargs.getposition) method and calculate the index of your current dropped item. I have implement it based on official [drag and drop](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) code sample. And you could use the following code directly.

```cs
private double rowHeight;
private async void TargetListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // This test is in theory not needed as we returned DataPackageOperation.None if
    // the DataPackage did not contained text. However, it is always better if each
    // method is robust by itself
    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        var targetListView = sender as ListView;
        if (targetListView.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            var listItem = targetListView.Items[0];
            var listItemContainer = targetListView.ContainerFromItem(listItem) as ListViewItem;
            var height = listItemContainer.ActualHeight;
            var marginTop = listItemContainer.Margin.Top;
            rowHeight = marginTop + height;
        }

        if (position.Y > rowHeight * targetListView.Items.Count)
        {
            var def = e.GetDeferral();
            var s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
            var items = s.Split('\n');
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                _selection.Add(item);
            }
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
            def.Complete();

        }
        else
        {
            double index = position.Y / rowHeight;
            var mathIndex = Math.Round(index, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            var def = e.GetDeferral();
            var s = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
            var items = s.Split('\n');
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                _selection.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(mathIndex), item);
            }
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
            def.Complete();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't look like this code can actually work: e.GetPosition gives me the relative position above the ListView, so if I have a long list, scrolled down the list and hovering between the 2nd and 3rd item in view, this code will give me an index of 2 but there are many items above that out of view. Second, this code assumes that all rows have the same height, which isn't the case in my app.

When I hover over items, the items move out of the way in the listview. Isn't there an event triggered when that happens? That would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Sure, the above answer is just apply for same row height. for different row height you could use foreach to calculate the total item's row height. The theory is same as the above answer.